# Does Ethereum Meta SE recommend or suggest where to ask philosophical questions?

Tags: support

I searched for an answer to this question here on Ethereum Meta SE but did not find any. **Are** there any recommended sites for philosophical questions about Ethereum? I have such a question that I would like to get others' opinions on.

Comment: Hello Ajoy, What kind of philosophical question? I'm curious!  You might try the Ethereum Forum, look at the categories, see if one fit, or maybe start a new one.  https://forum.ethereum.org/  You my also try on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/

Comment: Thanks, @Tesa. Will try the Ethereum Forum and Reddit. I did not mention above that I posted my question on Quora on Monday, July 10. Have not received any answers but 6 people are following it. Here is the link: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Does-Ethereum-really-give-us-trustless-transactions